# Java mail, set reply-to address not working

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I wrote a small email sending program in java, it has `from`, `to` and `reply-to` address, when the client tries to reply to the mail, it should be able to reply to the `reply-to` address. 
Currently it's not working, my code is below:

```
// File Name SendEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "xyz@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.from", "mnop@gmail.com");

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("New Message goes here");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

I used real gmail accounts. Can anyone help..?

Comment: It doesn't look like your code is attempting to set the reply-to address.

Comment: What about setting `mail.smtp.from`...?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Message.setReplyTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setReplyTo%28javax.mail.Address%5B%5D%29)?

Please note that:

- "from" is not the same as "reply to"
- according to the [spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-1-149769.pdf), the property for from-address is "mail.from"
- the documentation for [getDefaultInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance%28java.util.Properties%29) specifies that this only creates a new instance if there isn't an existing default instance and the properties are only used when creating a new instance.  Further, the default instance is a global value and will be re-used, so unless you want the same "from"-address on all your email, you need to create new sessions (using getInstance())

Answer (score 41):

Try:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setReplyTo(new javax.mail.Address[]
{
    new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress("mnop@gmail.com")
});
```