# Send email from user's email address in background in Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, jakarta-mail

I am building an android app that would let users send an email to my email address for comments and suggestions. I don't want to start an intent and have the user use their own mail app to send the email. I would just provide textboxes for their email address and their message and when they hit the "Send" button, it should get sent to my email address which is hosted in my own email server.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Java without having to ask the user for their password and opening another app? I tried the tutorial from [this site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) but I am not receiving any emails. I don't see any errors in logcat as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed out the last part of the [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

*If it is required to provide user-name and Password to the e-mail server for authentication purpose then you can set these properties as follows:*

```
 props.setProperty("mail.user", "myuser");
 props.setProperty("mail.password", "mypwd");
```

So essentially you need user-name, password for sending email from user's account.

Comment: Is it possible to use my own email as the sender and receiver but fake the headers to make it look like it's coming from the user? What I want is when I get the email, it will show the users email address and will reply to that address too.

Comment: Yes, you can always send an email to yourself. But why do you need to change the headers ? I am not sure you can do that. What you can do, is send an email with the subject containing the details of the customer like his name, email-address, for later processing.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if once I get the email in my mailbox, I can just hit reply to the user's email and not have to extract their information.

Comment: You can set the reply-to header in this case, see this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423928/3107043

Comment: I just ended up changing the "from" value to the users email address. And used my own account for authentication to my mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial and include the jar files specified 
**http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android**