# Authentication for webservice call in android

Tags: android, security, email, service, web

I was trying to write an android app that would send an email coming from the user's email address without opening up another email app. This should be done in the background. I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650978/send-email-from-users-email-address-in-background-in-android/20652473?noredirect=1#20652473) but it turns out, I would need to include the username and password in the code for this to work. However, I am not fully comfortable with this approach.

Now, what I'm thinking is to create a webservice hosted in my web server that would do the email sending. The android app will post to this webservice and send all the information (user's email address, message, etc.). This means that the webservice is available online and if someone finds out about it, they can utilize this service and I would get a bunch of spam mail. What is the best approach of adding security here? I'm thinking of sending a "secret code" along with the service request that will be verified in the server. Will users be able to sniff the data being sent to my webservice and read the "secret code"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  If your app contains credentials to the webservice, someone could simply decompile the app and extract the credentials or use network traffic capture software to observe what your app sends to your server.  Either way, you're exposed.

Your best bet is probably to limit the utility of your webservice to spammers by generating the email content server-side based on submitted fields.

Comment: The email is being generated server side so they really don't have any control over the content. But the issue is I don't want to receive a massive amount of email. This isn't a popular app so I think I won't worry about people decompiling the app. Just thought maybe there will be an easy way to prevent this.

Comment: You can't do much beyond obscurity.  Adding keys or auth data is really only another form of obscurity that is easily broken.  I'd just plan to change the API URL if someone does start abusing it -- make sure your app handles 404s gracefully by providing a useful error message: "sorry, error blah blah, please update this app" (the updated app using the new URL).